# Characteristics of a phase plane resulting from a second order autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been thinking about the possible phase planes resulting from a single second order autonomous ODE. I was hoping to verify that this reasoning is correct. Cnsider $y''=f(y,y')$. Then the phase plane would be constructed by considering the equivalent system of first order ODEs, for example with $v=y'$ we get

$\begin{cases}
y'&=v\\
v' &=f(y,v)
\end{cases}$.

I suppose this shouldn't be surprising, but it occurred to me that there are some restrictions on the possible resulting phase planes. I wanted to double check my reasoning here. Assuming the phase plane is the yv-plane, than any vectors with tails on the positive v axis *must* point to the right. Is this correct? My reasoning is that this is because the "run" of the vector corresponds to v, so for a positive v, it must point to the right. Is this correct?

A second question, which I suppose certainly must follow from the first, is if you were shown the vector field for a phase plane corresponding to a system of two 1st order ODEs that had vectors with tails on the positive vertical axis that *pointed to the left* you would be able to conclude that the system does not have an equivalent representation as a single second order ODE. My memory is (please correct me if I am wrong) that not all systems of two 1st order linear  autonomous ODEs can be represented as a single second order ODE, so this would make sense in this context as well.

In summary, I hadn't thought about this lack of equivalency between systems of 2 1st order ODEs and a single second order ODE in terms of phase planes specifically.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by equivalent representation? Are any transformations / changes of variables allowed? And what is initially given: a system or some arrows on a plane?

Comment: @AVK I was imagining just arrows on a plane. But I think I would still have the same questions about a system. Given a system of equations that can be equivalently represented as a second order ODE, must the characteristics of the vector field described in my question hold? If those characteristics of a given system do not hold, can you conclude that it can't be represented as a second order ODE? I haven't considered transformations or changes of variables. So sure, I'd be curious either way.

Comment: Yes they must. A similar conclusion can be made for the lower half-plane. This follows from the fact that the vector of the right side of an autonomous system at a point is a tangent vector to the trajectory of the system passing through this point. Here the answer is given to the question in which case a system of n first-order differential equations is equivalent to one equation of the n-th order: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4225889/transform-ode-system-of-first-order-into-ode-of-n-th-order/4225963